# What does an airport do with flights? "Receives"/"sends"?

Tags: word-request

What does an airport do with flights? "Receives"/"sends"? Maybe, instead of the first word, "accept" should be used, shouldn't it?

Comment: In what context do you want to use this? Give an example sentenced with a blank for the requested word.

Comment: I want 'airport' as a subject and 'flights' as an object. I need two verbs: for incoming flights, and for outcoming flights

Comment: sometimes the rules of English dictate using a different construction than you expect. An example of what you want to say about the flights and airports would make it easier to give you a useful answer. (For example, do you want to say there are lots of flights? That there aren't any flights to a particular destination? That they arrive at a certain time of day? That they make a lot of noise in nearby neighborhoods?...with an example sentence we can be much more helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say the airport *has* flights, for example, "How many flights does Detroit airport have every day". However this might be slightly informal for, for example, an academic paper.

We can also say the airport has some number of *arrivals* or *departures* each day, to be more specific.

More often, we turn the sentence around and make the flight the subject rather than an object. For example we can say a flight *arrives at* or *departs from* the airport.

Answer (score 1):

In the aviation industry, some (including me) say that an airport *launches* or *lands* a flight.

In reality it's the other way around, of course; the aircraft launches or lands from the airport, but it's convenient to use those terms from the point of view of the airport as well. (especially since, as your question demonstrates, there really aren't other good terms)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that it would depend on region and time. An airport receiving a flight, while not wrong, sounds very old fashioned. Airport flight cycles are commonly phrased as either arrivals (arrives, arrived, arriving, will arrives) and departures (departs, departed, departing, will depart, etc). An airport will average the same number of arrivals as they do departures unless there are extenuating circumstance. An arrival is a flight cycle. And a departure is a flight cycle. So, I would say that an airport cycles flights.